# Does shield surfing on rails lower shield durability?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've noticed that when I shield surf on minecart rails the shield seems to last longer than if I shield surf on solid ground. In fact, I've never seen a shield break from rail surfing. Does shield surfing on rails use up durability at all?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, shield surfing on rails does not affect durability.

---

According to [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tearsofthekingdom/comments/13o02eg/how_fuse_durability_actually_works/), some actions don't reduce durability:

- Hits that are non-reactive or have a small shine instead of the usual hit effect, like:

  - Hitting Zonai devices or shrine switches
  - Hitting a tree or rock with a weapon that can't damage it (Sticks, Bones, Spears, etc...)
  - Hitting Villagers or Koroks
- Hitting walls without collision (it's like hitting air)
- Cutting grass, small bushes, tree saplings, or other seemingly massless objects
- Temporarily lighting your wooden weapon on fire (it will instantly break eventually, except torches)
- Swinging a melee elemental weapon without hitting anything, like:

  - Windy weapons; like Rito weapons or weapons fused to a Korok-Frond or flat board
  - Weapons fused to Lizalfos Horns; Dragon Horns, Fangs, Scales, Claws, and Shard Spikes
  - Weapons fused to Gleeok Horns (which apparently have no elemental cooldown)
- Hitting a Lynel while riding its back (but not if the weapon is fused with a Gibdo bone)
- Successful shield parries
- **Shield surfing on snow, sand, or rails**

Comment: Are you saying that weapons with korok fronds, lizalfos horns, dragon horns, or gleeok horns are immune to breaking? That doesn't sound right. Or are those meant to be sub-categories of "melee elemental weapon without hitting anything"?

Comment: @Hearth it was poor formatting, let me clarify this

Comment: Can you mention the answer at the top of your post?

Comment: I can confirm that hitting a Lynel on its back does break fused Gibdo bones, though. Thought I was being clever with that but it still only lasted for one attack.